# Android Studio runtime error Stub! at com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver.<init>()

Tags: android-studio, gradle, kindle, amazon-device-messaging

When I build the Amazon (Kindle) flavor of my Android app I run into this Runtime error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
at com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver.<init>()
```

I need the local amazon-device-messaging.jar file to compile my app, however I do not need to include it during runtime as the amazon device will have the necessary classes and methods.

How do I update my Android Studio build.gradle file to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also ran into this issue. When adding the Amazon Device Messaging jar as a library, Android Studio automatically generated

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
}
```

I just needed to switch that to

```
dependencies {
    provided files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
}
```

That did the trick for me.  I'd up-vote your answer, @Clu, but I don't have a high enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I don't need the additional configurations details.  I'll try removing it to see if it still works.

Comment: Looks like your simpler answer is the correct way to do this, thanks!

Comment: I have the ADM jar inside an android-library project, though I have mentioned the dependency of the ADM jar as provided inside the build.grade file of the android-library project. Its am still getting this error. Any help?

Comment: @sanath01 did you ever figure this out. This didn't work for me either?

Comment: Neither it worked for me guys! Did you find something ?

Answer (score 5):

To solve this I used the `provided` type of dependency.

Inside my project modules **build.gradle** file, right before my `dependencies` closure I included the following:

```
configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}
```

And then, within my dependencies closure I included the following:

```
dependencies {
    provided files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
}
```

This ensured that the .jar was only used for compile time and not runtime.  I'm quite new to Android Studio, and this took me a while to figure out; hopefully this will help you make the switch to Android Studio as well.

Comment: If the library and the call to the library are in different packages, the 'provided' will be ignored and the stubbed-out library will instead be compiled into the APK anyway.  This can be resolved by putting the library in a Maven repo.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the ADM jar in the Maven local repository.

Command :

```
            mvn install:install-file "-Dfile=amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar" "-DgroupId=com.amazon.device.messaging" "-DartifactId=amazondevicemessaging" "-Dversion=1.0.1" "-Dpackaging=jar"
```

2. Include local maven repository as project dependency :

Add “mavenLocal()” in main Gradle build script:

```
            allprojects {
            repositories {
                            mavenCentral()
                            mavenLocal()
             }
```

3. Link the Maven artifact in ADM project.

Add below line ADMWrapperLib Gradle script (::).

```
            provided 'com.amazon.device.messaging:amazondevicemessaging:1.0.1'
```