# Amazon Device Messaging Stub! Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, amazon-device-messaging

I'm trying to integrate Amazon Device Messaging with Android Studio. First I followed ([integrating-your-app-with-adm](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/device-messaging/tech-docs/04-integrating-your-app-with-adm)). When I call

```
ADM adm = new ADM(getActivity());
if (adm.isSupported()) {
    // ...
}
```

There's this output on logcat:

> E/AndroidRuntime(24472): java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(24472):  at com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM.(Unknown Source)

So I followed Amazons ([Integrating Amazon Libraries with Android Studio](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=4872&tstart=0) ) with the same result.

Then I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24564473/5188726) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30027827/5188726) without success.

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="de.mypackage.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name=".permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
...
<application
    android:name=".MyPackageApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:allowClearUserData="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
...
    <service android:name=".service.ADMNotificationService" android:exported="false" />

    <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging" android:required="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".service.ADMNotificationService$MessageAlertReceiver"
        android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="de.mypackage"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
...
</application>
```

The local build.gradle looks like this:

```
...

dependencies {
    ...
    provided files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
    ...
}
```

May you have an idea?

Comment: Do you run the app on the Kindle device?

Comment: Yes! kindle fire hdx.

Comment: can you attach full build.gradle file or at least flavor/buildConfig sections and full dependencies section?

Answer (score 14):

You probably have something along this lines in your dependencies section:

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

This means you're compiling all jars in `libs` folder into your app. So probably the answer that says *switch `compile` to `provided`* works, but in addition to `provided` you do `compile` for all jars in libs folder anyway.

You would need to remove the `fileTree` line, and include any jars you have there (excluding `amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar`) manually.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to fix the crash is to edit the build.gradle (Module:app) file.

1. Remove the line: *compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')*
2. Go to the *libs* folder and find out all the jar files you require
3. Include them one by one for compilation. For example, *compile files('libs/ePOS2.jar')*
4. Add ADM jar file *provided files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')*
5. Build the project