# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate Android stub

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services

Sorry if this is a repeated question, it looks basic but I couldn't find any answer.
I'm trying to run Amazon's SNS KindleMobilePushApp demo app in a Kindle Fire tablet, but I get the following error:

```
    10-09 14:19:33.508    3101-3101/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b05228)
10-09 14:19:33.508    3101-3101/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.amazonaws.kindletest.ADMMessageHandler: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2315)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1231)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4533)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
            at com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.kindletest.ADMMessageHandler.<init>(ADMMessageHandler.java:32)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2312)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:127)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1231)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4533)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-09 14:21:08.359    3101-3101/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ Handle UnCaght exceptions. KILLING PID: 3101
```

This happens in the default constructor of this class of the sample project:

```
package com.amazonaws.kindletest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.Notification.Builder;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMConstants;
import com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase;
import com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver;

public class ADMMessageHandler extends ADMMessageHandlerBase {
    private static String savedMessage = null;
    private static int numberOfMissedMessages = 0;
    public static boolean inBackground = true;

    public ADMMessageHandler(){
        super(ADMMessageHandler.class.getName()); //ERROR!
    }

    ...
}
```

Which is derived from this class in Amazon's library:

```
package com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;

public abstract class ADMMessageHandlerBase extends IntentService {
    public ADMMessageHandlerBase(String var1) {
        super((String)null);
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    protected final void onHandleIntent(Intent var1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Stub!");
    }

    protected abstract void onMessage(Intent var1);

    protected abstract void onRegistrationError(String var1);

    protected abstract void onRegistered(String var1);

    protected abstract void onUnregistered(String var1);
}
```

I understand Amazon's class is a stub intended to be replaced by an actual implementation, but how is that done?. This is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral() // or jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.amazonaws.kindletest"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

And manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:amazon="http://schemas.amazon.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.amazonaws.kindletest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

   <!-- This permission ensures that no other application can intercept your ADM messages. It
   should have the form packagename.permission.RECIEVE_ADM_MESSAGE where packagename is the
   name defined in the "package" property of the manifest tag. --> 
    <permission android:name="com.amazonaws.kindletest.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <!-- Required permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazonaws.kindletest.permission.RECEIVE_ADM_MESSAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"        
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.amazonaws.kindletest.KindleMobilePushApp"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Your application's API Key -->
        <meta-data android:name="AmazonAPIKey" android:value="@string/api_key"/>

        <!--  Declare your ADMMessageHandlerBase implementation as a service -->
        <service android:name="com.amazonaws.kindletest.ADMMessageHandler" 
            android:exported="false" />

        <!-- You must explicitly enable ADM. You must also declare whether your application will run with or without ADM.
        If you specify android:required="false", your app must degrade gracefully when ADM is unavailable. -->
        <amazon:enable-feature android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging" 
            android:required="true" />

        <receiver android:name="com.amazonaws.kindletest.ADMMessageHandler$MessageAlertReceiver" 
            android:permission="com.amazon.device.messaging.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.REGISTRATION" /> 
               <action android:name="com.amazon.device.messaging.intent.RECEIVE" /> 
               <category android:name="com.amazonaws.kindletest"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have posted [posted about this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=677591&#677591) in Amazon's developer forum with no success yet. Please let me know if you need more information, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is why you get the issue :

You need the local amazon-device-messaging.jar file to compile your app, however you do not need to include it during runtime as the amazon device will have the necessary classes and methods.

Here is the solution :

Instead of

```
compile files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
```

you must use

```
provided files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
```

In your case : you can replace your dependencies by the following :

```
    ...
        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar', exclude: 'amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
            provided files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
        }
    ...
```

duplicate answers : [Android Studio runtime error Stub! at com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageReceiver.<init>()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560632/android-studio-runtime-error-stub-at-com-amazon-device-messaging-admmessagerece)

Answer (score 0):

In my case next solution has been helped to me:
put in the Manifest

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

More info: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79478779

Hope it helps someone! )