# Android Studio runtime error Stub! at com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase.() <init> (unknown Source)

Tags: android, android-studio, kindle-fire, amazon-device-messaging

When I build the Amazon (Kindle) flavor of my Android app I run into this Runtime error as following

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! at com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase().

Even though I added local `amazon-device-messaging.jar` file as dependency jar (provided) in my app, I am still getting this runtime exception.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/33482979/5723796

Comment: @SagarThakarar. thank you However it did not work i added dependency as Provided. still getting the same error

Comment: What are those error ?

Comment: @SagarThakarar RuntimeException: Stub! at com.amazon.device.messaging.ADMMessageHandlerBase.()

Comment: Paste your code